# how to convert string to List in dart? exapmle convert string `"["1", "2", "3", "4"]"` to list `[1,2,3,4]`

Tags: dart

I want to convert string `"["1", "2", "3", "4"]"` to list `[1,2,3,4]` in Dart language .

Comment: What you you tried yourself? What problems do you have with that solution? Maybe we can help you solve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting this on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true):

```
import 'dart:convert';

final list = '"["1", "2", "3", "4"]"';

void main() {
  print(jsonDecode(list.replaceAll('"', '')));
}
```

If your ***list*** is coming directly from an API you don't need the `replaceAll` methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want a list of strings or a list of integers.
Or whether there is a more general problem that you're trying to solve, which isn't just returning the list literal `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The simplest approach is

```dart
import "dart:convert";
  ...
  var stringList = jsonDecode(string);
```

which will give you a list of strings.
You can then convert that to numbers using:

```dart
  var numList = [for (var v in stringList) int.parse(v)];
```

or

```dart
  var numList = stringList.map((s) => int.parse(s)).toList();
```

Comment: jsonDecode getting error   Unhandled Exception: type '(String, {int? radix, ((String) => int)? onError}) => int' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'